# Bot is unresponsive even when a "message.channel.send" await is called. What is wrong?

Tags: discord.py

This discord.py project I have been working on in the past few days has given me nothing but trouble. To state what the issue is here. Basically the entire application is unresponsive, even when every await and every intent is enabled(on the commands.Bot main.py this is just an extension). I have tried every solution possible. I tried retyping keys and values for the dictionaries. And I even removed the embedded messages and replaced them with normal string messages. And I still got nothing. Here is a little snippet of the "problem". Anyways, I'd appreciate it if I could get some help on this?

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message, member:discord.Member=None):
  ARI=discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles,name=teamnames['ARI'])
  ATL=discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles,name=teamnames['ATL'])
  if message.content.startswith('<:ARI:844709003871387648> sign'):
    member = message.mentions[0]
    if ARI or ATL in member.roles:
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Signing Failed", description=f"**{member.mention} Wasnt Signed due to there being another team role in that users role. If this is incorrect, have this user either: \nAsk for Release or Demand from the team that they are currently roled as. . .**")
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Signing Transaction", description=f"**{member.mention} Was Signed to the <:ARI:844709003871387648> as the **`{len(ARI.members)}`** Player Signed Accordingly. If this was an error use command: <:ARI:844709003871387648> **`Release @user.mention`** To release the player of your initially signed roster.")
      await member.add_roles(ARI)
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You need to check if ARI is in `member.roles` separately from `ATL`. `ARI or ATL in member.roles` will evaluate to `ARI or T/F`

Comment: How to do this exactly? I have tried `if ARI in member.roles` aswell as `for role in member.roles` and set `role == ARI`

Comment: `if ARI in member.roles or ATL in member.roles` This probably won't solve your problem but it will lead you to the right direction

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggestion I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by reverting to dictionary keys and values, but a new error is now showing. And the bot is still for some reason unresponsive? Snippet below:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
@commands.has_any_role('Franchise Owner', 'General Manager', 'Head Coach')
async def on_message(self, message):
  if 'have signed' in message.content:
    member = message.mentions[0]
    teamemojis = ["ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "CHI", "CIN", "CLE"]
    teamsids = [784827425422573608, 784827426093793330, 784827440324804639, 784827439221047317, 784827427029385246, 784827427796025364, 784827441205477386, 784827442174623745,]
    teams=[]
    if teamsids.id in teamsids:
      teams.append(teamsids.id)
      step2=str(teams)
      step3=step2.replace("[","")
      step4=step3.replace("]","")
      print(step4)
      step5=teamsids.index(int(step4))
      print(step5)
      emote=discord.utils.get(message.guild.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
      team = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles,id=int(step4))
      pass
      if team not in message.author.roles:
        print('return')
        return
      elif team in message.author.roles:
        print('pass')
        pass
        if team not in member.roles:
          for role in message.author.roles:
            role.name == team.name
            await member.add_roles(role, reason="Signed by the Bot!")
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Signing Transaction", description=f"**{member.mention} Was Signed to the {str(emote)} accordingly. If this was a mistake, please refer to the `have released` Command in the bot commands**")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=emote.url)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        elif team in member.roles:
          await message.channel.send("**Cannot sign this user, as this user is already signed!**")
          return
```

Answer (score 0):

For an `on_message` event. Read the docs here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Adding the line:

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

at the bottom of the `on_message` event should make it function correctly again